# Convert String value to a Java Class name

Tags: java, android

I'm  bit stuck on this one, it's not too complicated but it's got me beaten!
What I'm trying to do is resume the user's session, by getting the name of the last activity and then passing it to an intent.
Where I'm stuck, is in converting the retrieved String into a classname, so the resumeIntent can use it.

```
   public void Resume (View view){
    SharedPreferences sharedPref =              
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
    String resumeName = sharedPref.getString("ActivityName", null);
    //probably need to do something here//
    Intent resumeIntent = new Intent (this, resumeName);
    startActivity(resumeIntent);}
```

Comment: have you tried `new Intent(this, Class.forName(resumeName))` ??

Comment: Thankyou very much, it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try ::

```
Intent resumeIntent = new Intent (this, Class.forName(getPackageName() + resumeName);
startActivity(resumeIntent);
```

**UPDATE**

```
String resumeName = YourActivityName.class.getCanonicalName();
try {
    Class newClass = Class.forName(resumeName);
    Intent resume = new Intent(this, newClass);
    startActivity(resume);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Store the canonical name of the activity in the string variable.

Comment: Thankyou, that was helpful.

Comment: Not to mention. If it was helpful and solved your problem, please mark this as an accepted answer.